# Overview of quasiquotation in Idris

Tags: reflection, idris

I hadn't realised that Idris has a quasiquotes until I came across [some tests in the test suite](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/test/quasiquote001/QuasiquoteBasics.idr).

Here's a short example in the REPL:

```
Idris> :module Language.Reflection
Idris> `(S Z)
App (P (DCon 1 1)
       (NS (UN "S") ["Nat", "Prelude"])
       (Bind (MN 0 "_t")
             (Pi (P (TCon 0 0) (NS (UN "Nat") ["Nat", "Prelude"]) Erased)
                 (TType (UVar "./Prelude/Nat.idr" 22)))
             (P (TCon 0 0) (NS (UN "Nat") ["Nat", "Prelude"]) Erased)))
    (P (DCon 0 0)
       (NS (UN "Z") ["Nat", "Prelude"])
       (P (TCon 0 0) (NS (UN "Nat") ["Nat", "Prelude"]) Erased)) : TT
```

I'd like to understand what that's all about. A brief overview and/or some references would be appreciated!

Comment: My pragmatist opinion is that leaving the `reflection` tag will help more people find this question when they are looking for it, than those it will hinder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper [*Elaborator Reflection: Extending Idris in Idris*](http://davidchristiansen.dk/pubs/elab-reflection.pdf) defines the Idris representation of Idris's core language called `TT`:

> The core language is represented by two separate data types:
>   `Raw` and `TT`. `Raw` is used to represent terms that are to be submitted
>   to the type checker, while `TT` represents terms produced by the type checker.

Figure 3 gives the following outline of `Raw` and `TT`:

> ```
> -- Variable names
> data TTName = ...
>
> -- Constants
> data Const = I Int | Str String | ...
>
> -- Binders
> data Binder : (tmTy : Type) -> Type where
>     Lam : (ty : a) -> Binder a
>     Pi : (ty, kind : a) -> Binder a
>     Let : (ty, val : a) -> Binder a
>     PVar : (ty : a) -> Binder a
>     Hole : (ty : a) -> Binder a
>     Guess : (ty, val : a) -> Binder a
>
> -- Terms which have not yet been typechecked
> data Raw = Var TTName
>     | RBind TTName (Binder Raw) Raw
>     | RApp Raw Raw
>     | RType
>     | RConstant Const
>
> -- Well typed, de Bruijn indexed terms
> data TT = P NameType TTName TT
>     | V Int
>     | Bind TTName (Binder TT) TT
>     | App TT TT
>     | TConst Const
>     | TType TTUExp
> ```

It also references the paper [*Type-Directed Elaboration of Quasiquotations*](http://davidchristiansen.dk/pubs/type-directed-elaboration-of-quasiquotations.pdf), which described the quasiquotation mechanism.

Comment: I've also been recommended [David Christiansen](http://davidchristiansen.dk)'s Ph.D dissertation for this topic: [Practical Reflection and Metaprogramming for Dependent Types](http://davidchristiansen.dk/david-christiansen-phd.pdf).